# MonoDroid - Beginner

Tags: android, xamarin.android

How are the Activitys and Layouts?

That is, if I have two different Activitys how do I tell what their respective Layout?

A greeting and thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read It.
An Activity is an application component that provides a screen with which users can interact in order to do something, such as dial the phone, take a photo, send an email, or view a map. Each activity is given a window in which to draw its user interface. The window typically fills the screen, but may be smaller than the screen and float on top of other windows.

An activity is a single, focused thing that the user can do. Almost all activities interact with the user, so the Activity class takes care of creating a window for you in which you can place your UI with setContentView(View).

Answer (score 1):

Go and look at the code.. u ll find something like `setContentView(R.id.YourLayoutName);`.. there u ll find it..